# HornetQ Consumer Stops Receiving Messages After N hours

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq

I'm using a HornetQ(v2.2.13) consumer, running standalone, to read off a Persistent topic published by a JBOSS server(7.1.1 final). All goes well for several hours (between 2-6) and then the consumer just stops receiving messages from the topic. From the log file on the server, I see data keeps getting pumped down the pipe but the consumer log file indicates the client stopped reading the data. I deduced that from the client saying the last time it read a message off the topic was 12:00:00 and the server log saying the last time it pushed a message to the topic was 14:00:00.

I've tried adjusting the HornetQ configs, but it doesn't seem to be working for a sustainable duration.

The code I use to communicate with the topic is as follows.

```
private TransportConfiguration getTC(String hostname) {
        Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, hostname);
        params.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, 5445);
        TransportConfiguration tc = new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), params);
        return tc;

    }

    private Topic createDestination(String destinationName) {
        Topic topic = new HornetQTopic(destinationName);
        return topic;

    }

    private HornetQConnectionFactory createCF(TransportConfiguration tc) {
        HornetQConnectionFactory cf = HornetQJMSClient.createConnectionFactoryWithoutHA(JMSFactoryType .CF, tc);
        return cf == null ? null : cf;

    }
```

Code snippet that creates the session and starts it:

```
TransportConfiguration tc = this.getTC(this.hostname);
        HornetQConnectionFactory cf = this.createCF(tc);
        cf.setRetryInterval(4000);
        cf.setReconnectAttempts(10);
        cf.setConfirmationWindowSize(1000000);

        Destination destination = this.createDestination(this.topicName);
        logger.info("Starting Topic Connection");
        try {
            this.connection = cf.createConnection();

            connection.start();
            this.session = connection.createSession(transactional, ackMode);
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
            consumer.setMessageListener(this);

            logger.info("Started topic connection");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("EXCEPTION!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get any log about server getting disconnected on the server's side.

Did you try playing with client-failure-check-period and other ping parameters?

What about VM Settings?

How are you acknowledging the messages? I see that you created it as transaction. Are you sure you are committing the TX as you recieve messages?

Comment: I'm not seeing any logs on the server side about disconnections, the only time I see any messages about disconnects are when I stop the server before the client and the client says it can't reconnect. Regarding TXs, I'm acking each message as soon as I get it.

Comment: Without a way to replicate it or having more information I can only guess. We have tested scenarios like this and we haven't found any issues. My guess is that you don't have paging configured, and another subscription is causing the system to block. You should either make sure you don't have a dead subscription (you created a subscription and forgot about it) or configure paging. Why don't you jump the discussion to hornetq user's forum where you can provide more info?

Comment: I'll start a thread over there either later today or tomorrow morning then. Thanks!

Comment: Check if you don't have a dead subscription. (what seems quite the cause).

Comment: I posted a new thread on the hornetq forums here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/199204?tstart=0